# I am getting this error while using zip function on List TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, oop, zip

```py
L1 = [1, 5, 2, 16, 32, 3, 54, 8, 100]
L2 = [1, 3, 10, 2, 42, 2, 3, 4, 3]

L3 = [x1+x2 for (x1,x2) in list(zip(L1,L2)) if L1>10 and L2<5]
```

Comment: you are comparing L1 to 10.  It isn't supported to compare a list to an int value

Comment: L1 = [1, 5, 2, 16, 32, 3, 54, 8, 100]
L2 = [1, 3, 10, 2, 42, 2, 3, 4, 3]

L3 = [x1+x2 for (x1,x2) in list(zip(L1,L2)) if (x1>10) and (x2<5)]
print(L3)

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you can't directly compare a list to an integer.

If you want to build L3 from the elements of L1 and L2 with conditions on these elements, perhaps this solves your problem:

```
L1 = [1, 5, 2, 16, 32, 3, 54, 8, 100]
L2 = [1, 3, 10, 2, 42, 2, 3, 4, 3]
L3 = [x1 + x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(L1, L2) if x1 > 10 and x2 < 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is what you want

```
L1 = [1, 5, 2, 16, 32, 3, 54, 8, 100]
L2 = [1, 3, 10, 2, 42, 2, 3, 4, 3]

L3 = [x1+x2 for x1,x2 in zip(L1,L2) if x1 > 10 and x2 < 5]
print(L3)
```

Out:

```
[18, 57, 103]
```